# How can I use timestamp for comparisons safely?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I'm running a tool to audit my smart contract and I got as report the following:

uses timestamp for comparisons / Dangerous comparisons :

```
require(block.timestamp > nextPayment, "Payement not due yet");
```

I've done more research and I found that block.timestamp can be manipulated by miners which is why is better to use other methods for comparison than block.timestamp

Do you have any method safer than this one ?

Nb: block.timestamp defines the Now in solidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The 15-second Rule** states that if your contract's code does not rely on a time interval of less then 15 seconds, than it is probably safe to use `block.timestamp` .

> If the scale of your time-dependent event can vary by 15 seconds and maintain integrity, it is safe to use a block.timestamp.

I understand that your smart contract is about recurring payments, so unless these payments' time interval is less than 15 seconds, your code is safe.

You can read more about Timestamp Dependence [here](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/development-recommendations/solidity-specific/timestamp-dependence/).

All the best!

Comment: This is no way shape or form solves the slither error "uses timestamp for comparisons"